# Ruby on Rails - Redirect/render via action does not work

Tags: ruby, redirect, action, render

I have the following code:

```
def isLoggedIn
    if session[:username].nil?
      puts "Not logged in!"
      return render :controller=>"admin", :action=>"login"
    end
  end
```

And the following code which calls this action at the top to check the status of the user.

```
def view_gallery
    isLoggedIn
       .
       .
       .
       .
      \/
    return render "view_gallery"
  end
```

The problem I am having is that the code continues to execute past isLoggedIn although the console is logging "Not logged in!" because as expected the user isn't logged in. This should then render an alternative layout which it doesn't do. If I mispell the action (say "logib") then it complains about a missing template - so I can see it running the render function.

The same occurs if I change render to redirect_to and/or if I move the return statement to the end of the line.

Any idea's?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Rails Guides says to do this in the following way:

`render :controller=>"admin", :action=>"login" and return`

Comment: But like I said in the original question, that does not effect the strange behaviour.

Comment: Actually, shouldn't the "render" be a redirect_to?  Also, moving IsLoggedIn to a before_filter would also be a good idea.